# Is any norm $||\cdot||:V\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ surjective?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Let $||\cdot||$ be a norm on $V$.

I know that when $V$ is nonzero finite-dimensional, $||\cdot||:V\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ is surjective.

Is it also true for the case $V$ is infinite-dimensional?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is true if and only if $V$ has dimension other than $0$. Just pick $x\neq 0$ in $V$. For all $\alpha\geq 0$, $$\Bigg\|\alpha\frac{x}{\|x\|}\Bigg\|=\alpha.$$